# Timeout when install rabbitMQ using powershell

Tags: azure-devops, rabbitmq, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to install rabbitMQ in windows server 2019 with Azure pipeline.
This is my code:

```
stages:
- stage: installRMQ
  jobs:
  - job: installRMQ
    displayName: installRMQ
    steps: 
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "##[command]Start-Process -Wait -FilePath \otp_win64_23.3.exe -ArgumentList `"/S`",`"/v`",`"/qn`""
        Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Users\Downloads\rmq\otp_win64_23.3.exe" -ArgumentList "/S","/v","/qn"

        Write-Host "##[command]Start-Process -Wait -FilePath \rabbitmq-server-3.10.2.exe -ArgumentList `"/S`",`"/v`",`"/qn`""
        Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Users\Downloads\rmq\rabbitmq-server-3.10.2.exe" -ArgumentList "/S","/v","/qn"
```

After installing Erlang, and switch to install rabbitMQ, I see rabbitMQ installed complete but PowerShell is still waiting. I've been waiting a long time but it seems to be permanently unable to complete the installation. How to solve this problem?

I tried removing -Wait and adding `Start-Sleep 120` but it seems that rabbitMQ does not install all the necessary files, leading to an error when using.

Update: my code only runs successfully when running the pipeline for the 2nd time. For the first run on a new VM, it is always unresponsive.

Comment: Do you see this issue using the latest version of RabbitMQ? https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.12.2

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue and am not sure why `Start-Process` does not return. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
& .\rabbitmq-server-X.Y.Z.exe /S /v /qn
Start-Sleep 10
& 'C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-X.Y.Z\sbin\rabbitmqctl.bat' 'await_startup'
```

If necessary, you can get various installation paths using the registry.

Instead of `Start-Sleep`, you can wait for epmd to report that the `rabbit` node has started. See how we wait for RabbitMQ for .NET client tests here:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/main/.ci/install.ps1#L86-L153

Comment: I have tried this method and installed RabbitMQ successfully but it seems RabbitMQ is still not fully installed. When running bat files in the sbin directory, the error is returned: The term 'erl.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script... ERLANG_HOME is not set correctly. I got this error many times when trying to install RMQ without -Wait. I made sure Erlang is fully installed and my ERLANG_HOME environment variable is correct.
I am required to use Erlang 25.3 and RabbitMQ Server 3.10.2